# Can't log in as a particular user after changing its password

Tags: password, users

I reset both of my accounts passwords but only one will let me log in.  So I logged in as that account since it has admin privs, I changed the password on the other account (My main one which I really need) and then tried again.  I have tried this several times with different passwords but no luck.  The home file system for this user looks okay.  What should I do?  If I delete the user, will I lose the files under home?

Comment: How are you changing the password? Can you login from the terminal? (Ctrl+Alt+F1, use F7 to get back)

Answer (score -1):

You can boot a live ISO and open a terminal :

```
chroot /path/of/your/root/filesystem
passwd
```

and then change the root password

Comment: That's much more complicated than it could be. Dropping to a recovery root shell is the easiest and fastest method if you have physical access.

Comment: I have tried both recommended methods, and at least it got one account going but the one I really need won't work.